# How to Identify Class A, B and C IP addresses that look similar?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

The question I had come up on my CompTIA test was `Which of the following is a private Class B IP address?`

The choices were

`A 10.0.15.1`,
`B 172.16.0.1`,
`C 172.16.1.1`,
`D 192.168.1.1`

We know that within a Class A IP address the first octate (out of 4 octates) starts with a 0,  so the first octate could be 01111111.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx, which leaves us with an IP address of 1.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx through 126.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx

However in Class B IP addresses, the first octate always starts with 10
(for example 10111111.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx) which gives us the possibility of 128-191 for the fist part of the IP address.

However, when I look at the above question, both `B` and `C` had 172, indicating that both `B` and `C` started with a `10` binary, which means that both `B` and `C` could be the correct answer.

The Correct answer, however, is `B`, 172.16.0.1

My question is, why is B correct and C is not?
What role does the 3rd part of the IP address play, a `0` and `1` in this case, that makes choice B correct and choice C incorrect?

Comment: The correct answer is "if you use IP classes, you're stuck in 1990's"... But still, chances are the test authors themselves made a mistake when selecting the answers, since all of 172/8 is definitely "class B".

Comment: Its a bad question, since they don't show you the masks, but it looks like they expected you to think that b is \16 and c is subnetted to \24 (which they might well be, but we can't tell). the question would have been unambigious if they asked which was a private class B **Network** instead of address. Either way, B is the wisest answer if you can only pick 1.

Comment: @grawity 172.16 to 172.31 is private

Comment: @GaneshR.: which is completely irrelevant to the determination of IP classes or routing in general

Comment: @grawity, that is correct, but it has everything to do with op's question.